# Cmake include_directories()

Tags: c++, include, cmake

This is my project tree:

```
project
| + src
| + external
| | + foo
| | | + include
| | | | - foo.hpp
| | | + src
| | | | - foo.cpp
| | | | - CMakeLists.txt
| | | - CMakeLists.txt 
| | + CMakeLists.txt 
| + src
| | - main.cpp
| - CMakeLists.txt
```

foo.cpp includes foo.hpp:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
```

Now the problem is that including the directory in the top CMake successfully find foo.hpp, 
but if I include in the subproject it doesn't. Any reason for it? (directories are included before the executable is compiled).

```
// project/CMakeLists.txt
include_directories(external/foo/include) //OK
add_subdirectory(external)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main foo)

// project/external/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(foo)

// project/external/foo/CMakeLists.txt 
include_directories(include) // NOT WORKING
add_subdirectory(src)

// project/external/foo/src/CMakeLists.txt 
add_library(foo foo.cpp)
```

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between `external/include` in the top-level CMakeList and `external/foo/include` in the CMakeList inside foo - perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: I made some edits, there might have been some errors before, but it should be ok now

Comment: The docs claim otherwise, but it seems the include directories are not inherited by subdirectories. You can test whether this is the case using a separate mini project.

Comment: Actually reading some posts looks like they do not propagate up, same for add_definitions...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Quoting the documentation for [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:include_directories):

> The include directories are added to the directory property
>   INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for the current CMakeLists file. They are also
>   added to the target property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for each target in
>   the current CMakeLists file. The target property values are the ones
>   used by the generators.

The [`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directory property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_dir:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) is inherited to all subdirectories and all targets in the directory.

- Specifying `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` for `include_directories` is redundant as relative paths are interpreted as relative to this directory by default. You should throw it out to increase readability.
- Specifying an include directory in both a subdirectory and its parent is redundant. You should avoid this and settle on one location.
- Use [`get_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:get_property) and [`message`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:message) to double-check that all directories and targets end up with the correct entries in their `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property.
- If you are free to require CMake 2.8.11 as a minimum requirement, consider abandoning `include_directories` completely and use [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_include_directories) instead. This has the advantage that include dependencies get resolved on a per-target basis exclusively which is usually the more desirable behavior.

Comment: well you would want to sepcify `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` if you want it to be in the compile commands json if set to true.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe a scope problem. I feel what you are trying to do here is to propagate setting from the `/project/external/foo/CMakeLists`  to  `/project/CMakeLists` and such that this setting can be propagated to `/project/src/CMakeLists`. But unfortunately, propagation from lower-level to higher-level CMakeLists is not possible in cmake, except for cached values. This means you will also need to add include_directories(`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/foo/include`) in the `/project/src/CMakeLists.txt`. Or, as you already did, you can just add this line in the top-level CMakeLists.

Comment: `But unfortunately, propagation from lower-level to higher-level CMakeLists is not possible in cmake, except for cached values` it's not true, for regular (non-cache) variables [PARENT_SCOPE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:set) can be used

Comment: `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is not recommanded, use preferably `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. See http://fujii.github.io/2015/10/10/cmake-best-practice/