# CMake Linking libraries from two different directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I currently have a directory that looks like this

```
dir1/
    dirA/
        dirAa/
              CMakeLists.txt <- add_library(x STATIC x.cpp)
    dirB/
        dirBb/
             dirBbb/
                    y is a static library that depends on DirAa (x) Library
```

How would I link those directories? using the relative paths didn't work when I tried linking y to x. in `y.cpp`, I've tried using `<x.h>` and `"x.h"`. When I used the former, depending on which line it's declared, `y.h` becomes undeclared.

in my dirAa CMake file, I have

`add_library(x STATIC x.cpp) 
install(TARGETS x DESTINATION lib)`

and in my dirBb directory, without the junk that I tried putting in:

`add_library(y y.cpp)
target_link_libraries(y <a library with install destination bin>)`
I'm trying to link y and x together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake include\_directories()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981534/cmake-include-directories)

Comment: It is not possible to answer without knowing the content of your cmake file(s). Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @wasthishelpful I've added the cmake snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't yet comment, hence replying here. I believe this is also the answer you are looking for!

The assumption is that you want to link `y` to the installed library `x`, not the original `x`. If so, you need the full install path of the item you are linking to so: `target_link_libraries (y ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/x)`. The rationale is that you would have defined `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` before the `install` command, hence this should work.