# CMake with multiple subdirectories not compiling

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, cmake, subdirectory

My Problem is that CMake is refusing to compile giving the following error:

```
 [orpheus@Poseidon build]$ make 
 sources : /home/orpheus/Projects/Personal/C++/test/testProj/src/helloworld/MyClass.cpp/home/orpheus/Projects/Personal/C++/test/testProj/src/helloworld.cpp
 headers : /home/orpheus/Projects/Personal/C++/test/testProj/include/helloworld/MyClass.hpp
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: /home/orpheus/Projects/Personal/C++/test/build
 [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TEST.dir/testProj/src/helloworld/MyClass.cpp.o
 /home/orpheus/Projects/Personal/C++/test/testProj/src/helloworld/MyClass.cpp:1:51: fatal error: testProj/include/helloworld/MyClass.hpp: No such file or directory
  #include "testProj/include/helloworld/MyClass.hpp"
                                                    ^
 compilation terminated.
 make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TEST.dir/build.make:63:      CMakeFiles/TEST.dir/testProj/src/helloworld/MyClass.cpp.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/TEST.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I am relatively new to CMake and have gone through most of the tutorials I can find as well as all the relevant stack overflow questions I could find, however nothing quite seems to cover my particular needs, I did (in my tweaking) stumble across a way where this didnt happen(unfortunately I cant replicate this now), however that gave me a linking error claiming:

```
 c++; fatal error: no input files
```

should I use the `include_directory()` command rather than `set()` to add the header files?

I decided on not using the `glob()` method of adding sources as per the  [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) and have based my solution off of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934295/add-source-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-cmake-project) and a variety of tutorials.

I have the following project structure:

```
test/
 |
 +--CMakeLists.txt
 +--build/
 |     |----CMakeFiles/
 |     |----etc
 |
 +--testProj/
 |     +----CMakeLists.txt
 |     +----include
 |     |       +----CMakeLists.txt
 |     |       +----helloworld/
 |     |       |        +----CMakeLists.txt
 |     |       |        +----MyClass.hpp  
 |     |
 |     |----src
 |     |     +----helloworld.cpp
 |     |     +----CMakeLists.txt
 |     |     +----helloworld/
 |     |     |       +----CMakeLists.txt
 |     |     |       +----MyClass.cpp
```

files are as follows:

### test/CMakeFiles.txt

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.1)
 project(TEST)
 add_subdirectory(testProj)
 add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${sources} ${headers})
 set_target_properties(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
 set(extraFlags "-Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=c++14")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${extraFlags})
```

### test/testProj/CMakeLists.txt

```
 include_directories(include)
 add_subdirectory(src)
 add_subdirectory(include)
 set(sources ${sources} PARENT_SCOPE)
 set(headers ${headers} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

### test/testProj/include/CMakeLists.txt

```
 include_directories(helloworld)
 add_subdirectory(helloworld)
 set(headers ${headers} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

### test/testProj/include/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt

```
 set(
    headers
    ${headers}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyClass.hpp
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

### test/testProj/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
 add_subdirectory(helloworld)
 set(
        sources 
        ${sources} 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/helloworld.cpp 
        PARENT_SCOPE
 )
```

### test/testProj/src/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt

```
 set(
    sources
    ${sources}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyClass.cpp
    PARENT_SCOPE
    )
```

please can someone point me in the right direction as i'm about to put my head through the monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Was indeed my 'include_directories()' that was the issue, I didnt realise that it is a [recursive command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981534/cmake-include-directories) making the work in the include subdirs redundant, I fixed this by adding the following line to my root `CMakeLists.txt`

```
 target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/testProj/include/)
```

and then modifying my `#include` statements to reflect that the `testProj/include` directory is now on my include path.

as well as removing the now redundant code the other CMakeList files in nested subdirectories

thanks to [Jacob Panikulum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5451259/jacob-panikulam) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`#include <MyClass.hpp>`

The quotes tell the compiler to look for a relative path. The header genuinely doesn't exist at that path relative to `MyClass.cpp`

The angle-brackets tell the compiler to start looking in your CMake `include_directories` folders. Since you did `include_directories(hello_world)`, the compiler will start looking in `include/hello_world` when you do include <*>.

Comment: when I use #include `"../../include/helloworld/MyClass.hpp"` and `#include "../include/helloworld/MyClass.hpp"` in MyClass.cpp and helloworld.cpp respectively then everything compiles fine. However i guess theres something wrong with my `include_directory()` statements as using `#include<MyClass.hpp>` doesnt work.